# Facebook PHP SDK Birthday APP using FQL and HTML

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I use a FQL query to get birthdays of user's friends. But I want to sort the users according to month and day, such that all birthdays in a given month must be in a div whose id is the 1st 3 letters in the name of the month as I use JS to show/hide months. Is this achievable?

Code so far..

```
$query = "SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, pic_square, current_location, hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strlen(birthday_date) != 0 ORDER BY birthday_date";

$prm  =   array(
      'method'    => 'fql.query',       
      'query'     => $query,
      'callback'  => ''     
      );

$friends  =  $facebook->api($prm);

$sort = array();
foreach($friends as $friend){
// note the extra 0's here, to give us padding to filter out duplicate  array keys
// this gives us an int in the format 030100, 093100, etc
  $key = (int)date('Md00', strtotime($friend['birthday_date']));

// make sure we don't have duplicates...if the key already exists, incrememnt it by one
  while(isset($sort[$key])) $key++;
  $sort[$key] = $friend;
}
// sort the items by array key
ksort($sort);
```

Thanks to [andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236331/andrew) and [david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475134/david) for helping me this far:)

Comment: You might need to improve your question or at least provide some of your Javascript code to see exactly how you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. Why not create an array of months to build the divs then display the users with birthdays in that month within that div...

```
<?
$months = array('jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec');

foreach($months as &$month){
?>
  <div id="<?=$month?>">
    <? // loop through users with birthday in $month ?>
  </div>
<?  
}
?>
```